# Is there any way to skip SAML authentication for special user?

Tags: saml-2.0, opensaml

SAML is new for me and I am trying to implement SAML-2.0 in my application, but I have to implement it in that way where i can skip SAML authentication for special users.

So can somebody tell me that how to achieve the same ?

Is there any special FLAG in SAML to switch-off/on based on  some condition.

please help.

Thanks & Regards:
Saurabh

Comment: I am using Spring 4.0 with SAML 2.0

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I guess you're the SP side in this specific SAML configuration. What do you mean by "skip"? do you have another login method for your application? (like a special login page). You don't switch SAML on/off, you just don't use it if you have another login method for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

Different authentication methods can be used for different entry points, think of Login with Twitter, Login with Facebook etc. If your special users know they're different, you could give them the option of being special. e.g. for SAML users:

```
https://yourapp.com/sso/
```

for special users:

```
https://yourapp.com/vip/
```

the second url would not use SAML. It would use whatever authentication special users require.